# JavaFX 11 drag and drop works wrongly for gesture target after resizing him

Tags: java, javafx, java-11

I got a next problem..
I add a simple *drag-n-drop* feature into my application to move cards from left and right **ListView**s to center table. That table is just a **GridView**. Grid children element perfectly received any drag events, it's all okay.

But.. if I resize an application window, I can't drag my cards to right and bottom parts of a GridView. May be this GridView just resizing, but JavaFX dragging provider just use old bounds? How I can fix it and 'say' to dragging provider about new GridView sizes?

Working environment:

- Oracle JDK 11.0.9
- Custom JavaFX 11.0.2 runtime image
- Linux (Kernel 5.10.11, build 170)
- GTK 2 (specified for JFX application using `-Djdk.gtk.version=2`)

`DragAndDropProvider.java` (main DnD class):

```java
public class DragAndDropProvider {
    
    public static final DataFormat SUBJECT_DATA_FORMAT = new DataFormat(SubjectCard.class.getName());
    public static final DataFormat TEACHER_DATA_FORMAT = new DataFormat(TeacherCard.class.getName());

    public static <T extends DatabaseCellDto<CARD>, CARD> void allowDragSourceFeature(ListView<T> listView) {
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        listView.setOnDragDetected(event -> dragDetected(event, listView));
        listView.setOnDragDone(event -> dragDone(event, listView));
    }
    
    public static void allowDragTargetFeature(LessonDto lesson) {
        lesson.setOnDragOver(DragAndDropProvider::dragOver);
    }
    
    private static <T extends DatabaseCellDto<CARD>, CARD> void dragDetected(MouseEvent event, ListView<T> listView) {
        // make sure at list item is selected
        T selectedItem = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if(selectedItem == null) {
            event.consume();
            return;
        }
        
        // determining the date format
        DataFormat dataFormat;
        CARD card = selectedItem.getCard();
        
        if(card instanceof SubjectCard)
            dataFormat = SUBJECT_DATA_FORMAT;
        else if(card instanceof TeacherCard)
            dataFormat = TEACHER_DATA_FORMAT;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported transfer object type: " + card.getClass().getSimpleName());
 
        // initiate a drag-and-drop gesture
        Dragboard dragboard = listView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
 
        // put the selected item to the dragboard
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.put(dataFormat, selectedItem.getCard());
 
        dragboard.setContent(content);
        event.consume();
    }
 
    private static void dragOver(DragEvent event) {
        // if drag board has an ITEM_LIST and it is not being dragged
        // over itself, we accept the MOVE transfer mode
        Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
 
        if(dragboard.hasContent(SUBJECT_DATA_FORMAT) || dragboard.hasContent(TEACHER_DATA_FORMAT))
            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
 
        event.consume();
    }
 
    private static void dragDropped(DragEvent event, LessonDto target) {
        // transfer the data to the target
        Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
        boolean dragCompleted = false;
 
        if(dragboard.hasContent(SUBJECT_DATA_FORMAT)) {
            SubjectCard content = (SubjectCard) dragboard.getContent(SUBJECT_DATA_FORMAT);
            target.updateSubject(content);
            dragCompleted = true;
        } else if(dragboard.hasContent(TEACHER_DATA_FORMAT)) {
            TeacherCard content = (TeacherCard) dragboard.getContent(TEACHER_DATA_FORMAT);
            target.updateTeacher(content);
            dragCompleted = true;
        }
 
        event.setDropCompleted(dragCompleted);
        event.consume();
    }

}
```

Application interface (Russian, sorry):
[image]

Comment: [mcve] please .. in English, please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved.
The solution is very simple.
When application window is maximized, stage's size still default, which was been set during initialization. (For example, 700 x 500) But actually that must be 1366 x 768 for example (it's my screen resolution).

I just use this code to fix it.
Just insert this code after initialization of your FXML controller :)

```java
        // stage is the window stage
        // we need the maximized property that mean is window maximized or not
        stage.maximizedProperty().addListener((a, b, isMaximized) -> {
            if(isMaximized) {
                // if this window is maximized, then we use
                // bounds maxX and maxY values than equals your
                // screen size parameters
                
                // mainPane is a root element in your FXML file
                // just set any FX:ID for that and use it here
                
                // you also can try Scene#getParent (cast to Region or any children)
                // to use him size parameters, but I prefer to use that
                stage.setWidth(mainPane.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX());
                stage.setHeight(mainPane.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY());
            } else {
                // overwise after window minimazing we just restore default
                // size parameters saved in the stage object
                stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth());
                stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight());
            }
        });
```